# Spam text showing under site URL in search results

Tags: wordpress, search, spam

I'm not a coder, so please keep responses understandable. ;)

I have a WordPress site with a GoDaddy registered domain. Recently my site has dropped off the search rankings. When I performed a search for my site today, I noticed that under the site URL spam text is now appearing as lines of text instead of cached site results. A search of my WP files and plugins reveals nothing, so I don't know how to solve this? The text is spam and pointing to another URL that is totally unaffiliated to my site. I suspect hackers have somehow embedded code somewhere to show this text when my site URL appears in Google Search.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: The code you see on the front end is probably Base64 encoded so when you search the files you don't find those strings.  Do you have code and data backups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your header.php.  They most likely got access to your site and then added the links in the header.  You should see a bunch of the links as soon as you open it up.  If you need help cleaning it out I could take a look at it for you but they should be right there.  It's a common thing with wordpress.  After you clean the spam out, you need to make sure your wordpress site stays updated and then install a security plugin like this one.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks so much Musik8101! Really helpful advice.

My site seems to have magically rectified itself after a month of searching to no avail and speaking to engineers. I updated my plugins and deleted spam comments so perhaps it's linked to that? Will add an extra (already have some security) plugin as you recommend. I checked the header file and all looks to be in order. 

Will update this thread if it happens again, but at least now I know what to look for. 

Really appreciate the response. :)